# Как изменить цвет иконки в SearchView?

Tags: android, icon, toolbar

Добавил в тулбар функцию `SearchView` цвет иконки, но в тулбаре она выводится черной. Если добавить точно такую же кнопку в тулбар без `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"` то иконка будет белой.

Я пробовал менять тему в **styles** на **light**, но ничего не помогло.
Может кто-то знает, где и что нужно изменить?

Код меню выглядит так:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_map"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_map"
    android:title="@string/action_map"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

**MainActivity**:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtered
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //Here u can get the value "query" which is entered in the ic_search box.
            if (!query.isEmpty()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + query));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**Styles**:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> </style>

<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#142a66</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1b3683</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/md_white_1000</item>
</style>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если добавлю иконку Search без `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"`

Код меню выглядит так:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_map"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_map"
        android:title="@string/action_map"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search_"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Данный виджет `"android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"` будет перекрашиваться в цвет меню в зависимости от выбранного стиля. Я думаю, что есть возможность программно перекрасить индивидуально его, но честно скажу, что это будет не очень правильная практика.

Как вариант попробуйте в `AndroidManifest.xml` изменить строчку на

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

тогда ваш ресурс файлы Style проигнорируется и вы увидите результат.

Answer (score 0):

Решил эту проблему, изменив тему тулбара **ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light** на **ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar**.

Тулбар выглядит так:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```